# 'ReduceLROnPlateau' object has no attribute '_implements_train_batch_hooks'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement learning rate scheduling in my convolutional neural network for which I implemented the `ReduceLROnPlateau` method but I encounter this error.

My list of imports

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
np.random.seed(0)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import itertools
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical # convert to one-hot-encoding
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPool2D
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.activations import selu
```

The code I'm using to implement it:

`reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2,patience=5, min_lr=0.001)`

The full error that I encounter

[image]

My code is working without the learning rate scheduler and this is the error I get whenever I try to callback this particular scheduler.

Thank you

Comment: What version of Tensorflow are you using? Can you parse your error log instead of a picture of it?

Answer (score 5):

Changing
`from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau` to
`from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau`
might resolve your error.
Most probably it is happening because you are mixing tensorflow and keras imports.